# Error after converting Sphinx original indexes to real-time indexes

Tags: sphinx

I used this tutorial to convert my original sphinx indexes to real-time indexes: http://www.ivinco.com/blog/converting-sphinx-original-indexes-to-real-time-indexes/

I changed my sphinx.conf:

```
source movies_dev
{
    type                            = mysql

    sql_host                        = localhost
    sql_user                        = ********
    sql_pass                        = ********
    sql_db                          = ********
    sql_sock                        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    sql_port                        = 3306

    sql_query                       = \
            SELECT \
                    CRC32(movie_id) AS id, movie_id, format_id, active, year, title \
            FROM \
                    movie;
    sql_attr_uint                   = format_id
    sql_attr_uint                   = active
    sql_attr_uint                   = year
    sql_field_string                   = movie_id
    sql_field_string                   = title

    sql_query_info          = SELECT * FROM movie WHERE CRC32(movie_id)=$id
    sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
}

index movies_dev
{
    source                  = movies_dev
    path                    = /var/data/sphinx/movies_dev
    morphology              = stem_en
    enable_star = 1
    min_word_len            = 3
    min_prefix_len          = 0
    min_infix_len           = 3
    charset_type = utf-8
    charset_table   = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F, U+DC->U+FC, U+C4->U+E4, U+D6->U+F6, U+DF, U+E4, U+F6, U+FC
}

index rt_movies_dev
{
    type                    = rt
    rt_mem_limit            = 32M

    path                    = /var/data/sphinx/rt_movies_dev
    charset_type            = utf-8

    rt_field                   = movie_id
    rt_field                   = title
    rt_attr_uint                   = format_id
    rt_attr_uint                   = year
    rt_attr_uint                   = active
}

source attach_movies_dev
{
    type                    = mysql

    sql_host                = localhost
    sql_user                = ********
    sql_pass                = ********
    sql_db                  = ********

    sql_query               = SELECT 1 FROM rt_movies_dev
    sql_query_post          = ATTACH INDEX movies_dev TO RTINDEX rt_movies_dev
}

index attach_movies_dev
{
    source                  = attach_movies_dev
    path                    = /var/data/sphinx/attach_movies_dev
    docinfo                 = extern
    charset_type            = utf-8
}
```

I created the "rt_movies_dev" table:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
SET time_zone = '+01:00';
SET sql_mode = 'NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `rt_movies_dev`;
CREATE TABLE `rt_movies_dev` (
  `movie_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `format_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `year` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`movie_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

After that, I run these three commands:

```
root@server:~# /usr/local/sphinx/bin/searchd --config /usr/local/sphinx/etc/sphinx.conf;
root@server:~# /usr/local/sphinx/bin/indexer --config /usr/local/sphinx/etc/sphinx.conf movies_dev --rotate;
root@server:~# /usr/local/sphinx/bin/indexer --config /usr/local/sphinx/etc/sphinx.conf attach_movies_dev;
```

No errors after the first two commands (except the warnings like in the tutorial).
But the last command throws this:

```
ERROR: index 'attach_movies_dev': No fields in schema - will not index.
```

I do not know exactly what the error says and I could find nothing useful. Can you say what's wrong? I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly attach_movies_dev source, connects to SPHINX, not to mysql. So no mysql table is required.

You are just using indexer to invoke SphinxQL commands.

But from what I can see trying to index the attach index, will always result in an error, because the RT index itself must be empty (so can attach a disk index to it!)

So change your attach index to connect to searchd instead. And it should work better. Probably an empty RT index, is ok, indexer will just create an empty index, but importantly it will still run the _post command. Which is the whole reason the index exists!

Also beware that your disk index and RT index have different fields, in your disk index, you have two sql_field_string, which create both attributes AND fields. So your RT index, should  to contain two string attributes to match (rather than just fields).

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer! But can you please give me a hint how I create an "empty RT index"? Does it mean that I have to delete "rt_field" and "rt_attr_unit" in the config file? You also wrote "So change your attach index to connect to searchd instead.". How can I implement that?
Sorry that I'm so unknowing in Sphinx.